# Can I send cross package notification for android app

Tags: parsing, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can I send cross package FCM notification using FCM or Parse push notification?
eg. I have app like OLA customer app and driver app now I want to send a notification from customer app to driver app and driver app to customer app

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by managing this on the server by calling API to send a notification to another app.